# how long is tofu good for?

Tags: storage-lifetime, tofu

I bought some tofu at the store about a month ago (or was it two months?). Anyway, I haven't eaten it all and it's sitting in my fridge in tupperware. How long is it good for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Throw it out.

Tofu has a very short life. Once opened it can last up to 5 days in the refrigerator, but only if you store it submerged in water, and change it daily.

See also: http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18509

Comment: if you're still in doubt, take a whiff of it... then you'll be sure to throw it out!

Comment: I once left some tofu in the fridge for two weeks, not knowing it would go bad, then ate it, and I really wondered why it tasted so bad.