# Extra Firm Tofu past expiration date: safe, but for how long?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, tofu

How long past the expiration date is pre-packaged extra-firm tofu safe, tasty and wholesome.  Generally, expiration dates are for sissies, but something about the tofu made me think twice.

I've seen the fresh tofu expiration question already posted: [how long is tofu good for?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6733/how-long-is-tofu-good-for) , but thought there may be a difference with the tofu from the grocery produce section.

Comment: "expiration dates are for sissies" - well, it's 8 years later, and I just cooked up the tofu my wife wanted to discard. Feb 15th expiration, so 10 weeks expired. It smelled fine and tasted as good as when it's 3 months younger. Not planning to push my luck that far again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tofu is high in protein, with a neutral PH. And it (normally) doesn't contain any preservatives like salt, sugar or nitrates. Bacteria love foods like that. If it's past the date, chuck it out.

Comment: +1 Tofu is cheap and it smells TERRIBLE when it goes bad.